# set featured image after upload wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-featured-image

i have this code which is working fine to insert the uploaded photo inside library in wordpress and it create the post successfully

but it didn't work to set the uploaded photo as featured image on the post

Note: im using custom post types.

i have try a tons of solutions on stackoverflow network and nothing work out

```
$dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
   $file_path = $dir."/uploads/";
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    $user = $_POST['usr'];
    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path);


$file = $file_path;
$filename = basename($file);

$upload_file = wp_upload_bits($filename, null, file_get_contents($file));
if (!$upload_file['error']) {
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_parent' => $parent_post_id,
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_file['file'], $parent_post_id );
    if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $upload_file['file'] );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id,  $attachment_data );
    }
}

unlink($file_path);

$user = get_userdatabylogin($_POST['usr']);
$user_ID = $user->ID; // prints the id of the user

global $user_ID;

$new_post = array(
'post_title' => 'My New Post',
'post_content' => $_POST['text'],
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'taken_photos',
'post_category' => array(0)
);
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

  update_post_meta($pid, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);

  $attachment_data = array(
    'ID' => $attachment_id,
    'post_excerpt' => 'TITLE'
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $file_path = $dir."/uploads/".date("Y")."/".date("m");
```

Can you please make the file path like that.Hope it will work for you.

Comment: the `$file_path` has nothing to do with it also this file path is temporary and if you take a good look to the code you will see that im deleting this file after it's get inserted inside the wordpress media library

Answer (score 0):

after your line

```
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id,  $attachment_data );
```

add additional line

```
add_post_meta($parent_post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);
```